# Convert .NET Standard class library to native aar/jar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

Currently, we are developing a .NET Standard class library that will be used by different Xamarin.* platforms.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the shared code in a native Android project (maybe produce an AAR/JAR file).

The reason I need this functionality is because our company provides an AAR to one of our customers (that is used by a native Android project), and we would like to keep a single source base instead of two.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

#### Update:

The name changed to ".NET Embedding" and it is at v0.4 at the time of this update.

- https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/dotnetembedding/dotnetembedding_0/dotnetembedding_0.4/

#### New instructions:

- [Installing .NET Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/install/install)

#### Original post:

You can use Mono's `Embeddinator-4000`

> It supports various language consumers, so it surfaces .NET code as idiomatic code in the target language. This is the list of supported languages at present:

- Objective-C: mapping .NET to idiomatic Objective-C APIs.
- Java: mapping .NET to idiomatic Java APIs.
- C: mapping .NET to an object-oriented like C APIs.

> Embeddinator-4000 is a tool that allows your existing .NET Code (C#, F# and others) to be consumed from other programming languages and in various different environments.
>
> Java is currently in a preview state for macOS, Windows, and Android.
>
> The platform is selected by passing the --platform= command-line argument to the embeddinator. Currently macOS, Windows, and Android are supported.

re: https://mono.github.io/Embeddinator-4000/

As a part of the requires For Android you will need `Xamarin.Android` 7.4.99+ and Android Studio 3+ (Java 1.8) but if you are building Android apps with Xamarin and Java you would have those already.

Note: This tool is in **Preview**, so review the open issues and post new if needed.

re: https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000/issues

Note: This is not trans-compiling, but embedding Mono's runtime in a native package that allow CIL code, AOT'd (i.e. iOS) or not to run within a different language/runtime.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it out. Thank you very much!