# Adding Xamarin to multiple Native mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

We have a number of existing native mobile applications that I would like to add a new major feature to. Is it possible to keep the existing native apps but integrate Xamarin into them for the new features?

I am aware that Xamarin can call native Java / Objective-C libraries

I am also aware that Embeddinator-4000 enables native code to call .Net code: [Convert .NET Standard class library to native aar/jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520285/convert-net-standard-class-library-to-native-aar-jar)

Can both the Native and Xamarin code produce UIs at the same time?

Is such a Native / Xamarin hybrid possible?

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover , this is not a duplicate, I have updated the question to clarify the difference.

Comment: The answer is yes, review the Embeddinator-4000 docs. It is in preview and has a lot of rough edges and since you are embedding the mono runtime, assemblies, and java dex in a `.AAR`, do not expect it to be a small aar. Personally the memory/cpu overhead of adding a Mono runtime via NDK-based Java wrappers is really high when you already have a Java/native app, but you should evaluate it yourself.