# Can I use Xamarin/Portable Class Libraries to build a C# library that can be used by Swift or Objective-C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, swift, xamarin, portable-class-library

We have been working for the last year on a set of .NET libraries with a C# API to provide an SDK for third party UI developers. This SDK was originally intended to run on Microsoft platforms (notably a Surface Pro). However recently we've been tasked with estimating the effort for providing "multi-platform" support for these libraries (by multi-platform I mean both Windows and iOS, for an iPad).

I have found some sites suggesting this isn't possible, but I'm wondering with Microsoft's integration of Xamarin over the last couple years, if anything has changed? Our current plan is to rewrite the SDK in C++ with a C wrapper, but if there was a way to utilize PCLs or Xamarin to do this, it would be awesome. The important caveat is that the library must be accessible by native iOS languages, not just Xamarin.iOS, as we don't want to lock the third party UI developers into a specific language.

The SDK has no UI functionality, it is all low level network communication, XML parsing, and data decoding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520285/convert-net-standard-class-library-to-native-aar-jar/46520312#46520312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.NET Embedding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/dotnet-embedding/) is available as a preview

> .NET Embedding allows your existing .NET Code (C#, F#, and others) to
>   be consumed from other programming languages and in various different
>   environments.
>
> This means that if you have a .NET library that you want to use from
>   your existing iOS app, you can do that. Or if you want to link it with
>   a native C++ library, you can also do that. Or consume .NET code from
>   Java.

Comment: I had not heard of .NET embedding until now. Looks awesome and exactly what we're after. Time to fire up the Embeddinator-4000!