# Can I use Mono Ahead of Time compiler with a Xamarin.Android library?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, aot

I have a .dll built from a Xamarin Android Library project and I'm trying to compile it using AOT by running the following command, as I saw in [this article](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/):

> mono --aot --verbose path/to/the/dll/project.dll

But i'm getting some errors and it says, when it finishes:

> AOT of image [dll path] failed

The errors are like the following:

```
Can't find custom attr constructor image: ..\Reports\Reports\bin\Release\Reports.dll mtoken: 0x0a000004 due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.
```

It is throwing that with all the assemblies that the library uses (System.dll, System.Core...)

So I don't know if this can't be done or I am doing something wrong (any parameter missing in the command or something). Could someone clear me out?

Comment: You would need to cross-compile that IL assembly for ARM, and while you can do that, how do you want to consume the resulting ARM shared library (`.so`)?

Comment: My idea was to consume the .so either from a Xamarin.Android or Android Studio app so that the app hasn't to compile the .dll by itself. I don't know how would I do this or even if I can do it, that's why I was wondering first if it would be possible to create the .so file.

Comment: If you want to consume it from a native Java Android app:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520312/4984832 Otherwise the issue consuming it within a Xamarin.Android application becomes you do not have anything to compile against (i.e. the IL assembly) and if you embed Mono within it, then you  have to define either a Java native interface or a C# DllImport based one to consume it, plus take the huge hit on performance.

Comment: Yeah I already knew about Embeddinator but I had problems with it because the generated .aar doesn't have the libsqlite.so (I've already opened an issue). The thing I was wondering is that if I do an AOT compile of the .dll, would it have better performance than, for example, using the .dll directly from Xamarin.Android app?