# Invoke C# code from a Swift or ObjC application

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin, razor

I need to invoke some C# code from a Swift/ObjC iOS app. What are my options?

I though I could compile the C# code using Xamarin into an iOS framework, but that doesn't seem possible. The opposite is easily done - I could invoke an ObjC framework from a Xamarin iOS app, but that's not what I need as my iOS app is already written.

The C# code in question is Razor, if that matters. It has to be Razor, no alternatives like Handlebars will work for me.

Comment: .NET Embedding/Mono Embeddinator-4000 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520312/4984832

Comment: Thank you, that seems exactly the right thing. If you could make it an answer I would accept it. Maybe pad it with some text from the target page to bypass the automatic answer-to-comment conversion?

Comment: For posterity: Embeddinator-4000 is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/

Comment: Better link with getting-started: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/objective-c/ios